# Adodb Connection To Outlook Calendar Appointment

Tags: vb.net, outlook, adodb

I'm connecting to Outlook using Adodb. (ADO is a requirement)

```
  With ADOConn
     .Provider = "Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0"
     .ConnectionString = "Exchange 4.0;" _
                                & "MAPILEVEL=" & mailboxname & "|;PROFILE=Outlook;" _
                                & "TABLETYPE=0;DATABASE=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\;"
     .Open()
 End With
```

then using the sql

```
   Select * from Calendar
```

which returns the Appointments, but with no start or finish times.

Does anyone know how I can retrieve this information this way?

Comment: I tried really hard to do it with ADO and with ADO.NET using an OleDbConnection. It just does not work. ADO does not return the required columns. ADO.NET gives an "ISAM not installed" error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use ADODB? If not, you can try this:

```
Dim ola As New Outlook.Application
Dim oln As Outlook.NameSpace = ola.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim olc As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oln.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
For Each item As Outlook.AppointmentItem In olc.Items
    MsgBox(item.Subject & vbCrLf & item.Start & vbCrLf & item.End)
Next
```

If you do have to use ADODB, then can you post the portion of the code where you are trying to read the start and end times?

Comment: I will get the code i'm using soon, but it is a requirement, that i don't have control over, to use ADO